# Is $f'/f$ uniformly bounded as $f$ ranges over a certain family of functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\epsilon>0,\, \alpha>1.$ Does there exist a family of differentiable functions  $f_\epsilon:[0,1]\to\mathbb R_+$ such that
\begin{align}
   f_\epsilon(1) &= \alpha, \\
   f_\epsilon'(1)&=1, \\
   f_\epsilon'(0)&=0, \\
   f_\epsilon(0)&=\epsilon,
\end{align}
satisfying the additional requirement that $\left\|\frac{f_\epsilon'}{f_\epsilon}\right\|_\infty$ stays bounded as $\epsilon\to 0$ ?

Comment: Already the conditions $f_\epsilon(0)\to0$ when $\epsilon\to0$, and $f'_\epsilon(x)\leqslant Cf_\epsilon(x)$ uniformly in $\epsilon>0$ and $x$ in $(0,1)$, imply that $f_\epsilon(1)\to0$ when $\epsilon\to0$, hence no, there exists no such family of functions $(f_\epsilon)$.

Comment: Oh, you're right, that's Gronwall's inequality, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem,

$$\tag 1 \ln \alpha - \ln \epsilon = \ln f_\epsilon (1) - \ln f_\epsilon (0) = (\ln f_\epsilon)'(c_\epsilon)=\frac{f_\epsilon'(c_\epsilon)}{f_\epsilon(c_\epsilon)}.$$

As $\epsilon \to 0^+,$ the left side of $(1)$ $\to \infty.$ Therefore there is no uniform bound on $\|f_\epsilon'/f_\epsilon\|_\infty.$